# Is a product of derivatives still a derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable functions, does $f'g'$ always have an antiderivative ?

---

*Origin of the question :* $\ $  At first I considered two functions s.t. both $f'$ and $g'$ are locally bounded (thus locally Lebesgue integrable), and s.t. every point in $\mathbb{R}$ is a [Lebesgue point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point) for $f'$ and $g'$. Then it is not hard to show that every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is also a Lebesgue point for $f'g'$, and thus $x \mapsto \displaystyle{\int_0^x} f'(s)g'(s)ds$ is differentiable and its derivative is $f'g'$.

My problem is that in the general case, I do not manage to find a form for the antiderivative without, at some point, using integrals which are not always defined...

Comment: I don't know offhand, but note that the standard polarization trick,$$f'g' = \tfrac{1}{2}\bigl((f' + g')^{2} - (f')^{2} - (g')^{2}\bigr)$$reduces the problem to finding an antiderivative for the square of a derivative.

Comment: The product of two derivatives is not necessarily a derivative. In fact, the product of a derivative and a continuous function is not necessarily a derivatives. If nobody else answers, I'll try to look up the counterexamples or references.

Comment: A quick web search turned up ["Generic continuous functions and other strange functions in classical real analysis"](http://scholarworks.gsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1043&context=math_theses) by Douglas A. Woolley, a Master's thesis at Georgia State U. It says that the product of a derivative and an absolutely continuous function is a derivative, but gives an example of a derivative and a continuous function whose product is not a derivative. References to W. Wilkosz, Some properties of derivative functions, Fund. Math. 2 (1921) 145-154 and J. Foran, On the product of derivatives, 1979

Comment: "1979" in my previous comment was a typo. The correct reference is: J. Foran, On the product of derivatives, Fund. Math. 80 (1973), 293–294.

Comment: Thank you for all your useful comments ; as pointed out above, this question had already been asked